# Why does my customized WPF RadioButton not look right?

Tags: wpf, checkbox, radio-button

I am replacing the style of a radio button with that of a check box.  I know you are going to say that is a bad idea, but it really needs to work this way.  Anyway, using Expression Blend I was able to extract the style of the CheckBox and apply it to a RadioButton.  My only problem is now that when it draws there is no border.  Can anyone tell me why?  Here is the code (THIS HAS BEEN UPDATED SINCE THE ORIGINAL POST):

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.Window1"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:Microsoft_Windows_Themes="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Themes;assembly=PresentationFramework.Royale"
Title="Customized RadioButton" Width="496" ShowInTaskbar="True" ResizeMode="NoResize" Height="105">
<Window.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="CheckBoxStroke" Color="#8E8F8F"/>

    <Style x:Key="RadioButtonCheckBoxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#F4F4F4"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource CheckBoxStroke}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}">
                    <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                        <BulletDecorator Background="Transparent">
                            <BulletDecorator.Bullet>
                                <Microsoft_Windows_Themes:BulletChrome Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" IsChecked="{TemplateBinding IsChecked}" IsRound="false" RenderMouseOver="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}" RenderPressed="{TemplateBinding IsPressed}"/>
                            </BulletDecorator.Bullet>
                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" RecognizesAccessKey="True"/>
                        </BulletDecorator>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="HasContent" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="4,0,0,0"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<StackPanel>
    <CheckBox Height="16" Name="checkBox1" Width="120">CheckBox</CheckBox>
    <RadioButton Height="16" Name="radioButton1" Width="120">RadioButton</RadioButton>
    <RadioButton Content="RadioButton with CheckBox Style" Margin="4" Style="{DynamicResource RadioButtonCheckBoxStyle}" FocusVisualStyle="{x:Null}" GroupName="Header" IsChecked="False" IsEnabled="True" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
</StackPanel>
```

[alt text http://img260.imageshack.us/img260/65/33733770.jpg](http://img260.imageshack.us/img260/65/33733770.jpg)

To see how this displays, please paste it into Visual Studio.  You will see that the Customized RadioButton doesn't look correct.  It is missing the regular 3D effects that a CheckBox normally has.  I don't care about any content (I won't be having any) I just want it to look like a normal CheckBox.

Comment: If you want full looks of a checkbox, it might be easier to just use CheckBoxes, and manually uncheck the other boxes in the group when another is selected. While my answer below will likely get your border back, it won't create the full 3D effect necessarily.

Comment: Have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975333/how-do-i-make-a-checkbox-look-like-a-radiobutton

Answer (score 2):

Since you're overriding the template, you need to attach to the class's properties yourself.

Declare a border in the template in the following fashion:

```
<Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"/>
```

Also, you've got a small bug. You've defined the setter for "BorderBrush" multiple times in your style.

**Edit:** After seeing your image, here's your real issue:

```
<Microsoft_Windows_Themes:BulletChrome Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" IsChecked="{TemplateBinding IsChecked}" IsRound="false" RenderMouseOver="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}" RenderPressed="{TemplateBinding IsPressed}"/>
```

You were missing the BorderThickness in your bullet. It was effectively setting your thickness to 0, which is why you didn't see anything.

Comment: Where do I add that code?  I've tried putting in the ControlTemplate, but it doesn't compile.  Thank you for your help, Will.

Comment: It depends on what you want the border to surround. I would assume inside the ControlTemplate declared in your `RadioButtonCheckBoxStyle`, as Drew Marsh's answer also indicates, but you could try it within your `<BulletDecorator>`.

Comment: See my edit, you're missing `BorderThickness` in your bullet declaration.

Answer (score 0):

An image might help here, but where do you expect the border to be? Are you expecting a border around the entire content?? The only border there should be according to the template you're using is around where the check mark will be. If you want a border around all the content then you need to add a `Border` into the `ControlTemplate` like so:

```
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}">
                        <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                            <BulletDecorator Background="Transparent">
                                <BulletDecorator.Bullet>
                                    <Microsoft_Windows_Themes:BulletChrome Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" IsChecked="{TemplateBinding IsChecked}" IsRound="false" RenderMouseOver="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}" RenderPressed="{TemplateBinding IsPressed}"/>
                                </BulletDecorator.Bullet>
                                <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignme    nt}" RecognizesAccessKey="True"/>
                        </BulletDecorator>
                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                    <Trigger Property="HasContent" Value="true">
                                    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource CheckRadioFocusVisual}"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="4,0,0,0"/>
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
```

**Side note:** You have set `FocusVisualStyle="{x:Null}"` on the Checkbox itself, but your template changes this property in its `HasContent` property trigger. If you really don't want a FocusVisualStyle you should remove that setter.

Comment: Will Eddins' revised answer is correct, you're missing BorderThickness on the BulletChrome.