# How do I make a CheckBox look like a RadioButton

Tags: wpf, checkbox, radio-button, styles

I wanna use a CheckBox but I want it to have the RadioButton chrome.

What's the easiest way to do this?

Comment: Your users will love you for it.

Comment: Any reason you can't use a set of RadioButtons that behave like checkboxes?

Comment: I want to use a DataGridCheckBoxColumn, I basically want to use a cross-row RadioButton, I know I can use DataGridTemplateColumn setting the CellTemplate and CellEditingTemplate but I thuoght DataGridCheckBoxColumn is less verbose.

Comment: you mean checkbox should be in round shape like RaidoButton..?

Comment: This sounds like a bad idea as a user will have certain expectations as to how a control will behave and you are changing that.

Comment: @Thilo, @benPearce thanks, I appreciate your time, will take that into account.

Comment: I actually ran across a VERY good reason to do this.  I'm using a Telerik RadGridView control with RowDetailTemplates.  Inside each template are, among other controls, Radiobuttons.  Even with the GroupName set, setting one radio button sets all the rows!  Using checkboxes is the only answer because Telerik cannot fix this issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
public partial class RadioCheckBox : CheckBox
{...}
```

RadioCheckBox.xaml:

```
<CheckBox
x:Class="WpfApplication1.RadioCheckBox"
...
xmlns:m="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
>
<CheckBox.Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type m:RadioCheckBox}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type m:RadioCheckBox}">
                    <Grid>
                        <RadioButton
IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, 
Path=IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}"
IsHitTestVisible="False" />
                        <CheckBox
IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, 
Path=IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}" Opacity="0"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</CheckBox.Style>
```

Comment: Actually a great idea, but I think inheriting from CheckBox is unnecessary, just have the CheckBox template as you said, bound to FindAncestor of type CheckBox and set its IsChecked value accordingly.

Comment: thanks man! i changed the m:RadioCheckBox to CheckBox for my .net (3.5)

Comment: It may be that .NET 4.5 works differently, but VS is telling me that style is invalid because "TargetType does not match type of element 'CheckBox'".

Comment: So, what is happening here? Why does this work? Are we just overlaying an invisible checkbox (so our interaction with the checkbox still produces checkbox behavior) and displaying a radio button behind it (so we see a radiobutton, but get the behavior of the invisible checkbox?)

Answer (score 2):

This actually works just like I desired:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}" x:Key="CheckBox_RadioButtonStyle">
  <Setter Property="Foreground" 
Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
  <Setter Property="Background" Value="#F4F4F4"/>
  <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#8E8F8F"/>
  <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
  <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle">
    <Setter.Value>
      <Style>
        <Setter Property="Control.Template">
          <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
              <Rectangle Margin="1" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" 
Stroke="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}" 
StrokeThickness="1" StrokeDashArray="1 2"/>
            </ControlTemplate>
          </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
      </Style>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
        <BulletDecorator Background="Transparent" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
          <BulletDecorator.Bullet>
            <themes:BulletChrome BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
IsChecked="{TemplateBinding IsChecked}" 
RenderMouseOver="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}" 
RenderPressed="{TemplateBinding IsPressed}" IsRound="True"/>
          </BulletDecorator.Bullet>
          <ContentPresenter 
HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" 
Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" 
SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" 
VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
        </BulletDecorator>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
          <Trigger Property="HasContent" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" 
              Value="{StaticResource CheckRadioFocusVisual}"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="4,0,0,0"/>
          </Trigger>
          <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" 
          Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
          </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>


<!-------------------------------------->

<DataGridCheckBoxColumn x:Name="colSelected" Header="Selected" 
    ElementStyle="{StaticResource CheckBox_RadioButtonStyle}"/>
```

Comment: Yea copy and pasting this doesn't work. You have two things, the themes xmlns and the CheckRadioFocusVisual static resource which you did not define anywhere. If you're using expression blend you should really strive to either include these missing things or note that there are non-standard xmlns included in your xaml.

Answer (score 1):

XAML:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dg">
    <DataGrid.GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="Test"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
        </GroupStyle>
    </DataGrid.GroupStyle>
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="myStyle" TargetType="CheckBox">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="CheckBox">
                        <RadioButton IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=CheckBox}}"
                                Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                GroupName="{Binding MyProperty}"/>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>

    </DataGrid.Resources>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn ElementStyle="{StaticResource myStyle}"
                                EditingElementStyle="{StaticResource myStyle}"
                                IsReadOnly="False"
                                Binding="{Binding Flag, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                                Header="1"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Code-Behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        object[] items = new object[] {
            new MyClass() { Flag = false, MyProperty = 1 },
            new MyClass() { Flag = false, MyProperty = 1 },
            new MyClass() { Flag = false, MyProperty = 1 },
            new MyClass() { Flag = false, MyProperty = 1 },
            new MyClass() { Flag = false, MyProperty = 1 },
            new MyClass() { Flag = false, MyProperty = 2 },
            new MyClass() { Flag = true, MyProperty = 2 },
            new MyClass() { Flag = false, MyProperty = 2 },
        };

        ICollectionView cv = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(items);
        cv.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("MyProperty"));
        this.dg.ItemsSource = cv;
    }

    public class MyClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public int MyProperty { get; set; }

        private bool flag;
        public bool Flag
        {
            get { return this.flag; }
            set
            {
                this.flag = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged("Flag");
            }
        }
        #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void OnPropertyChanged(string propName)
        {
            if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
            }
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: It behaves like a regular RadioButton and only one row can be selected, **probably this is the right answer**, the question is just how can I set RadioButton groups, let me explain, I have 100 rows, from each group of rows I have to select 1 row.

Comment: In addition, it doesn't change the bound property, and also sometimes is rendered like a CheckBox for some reason.

Comment: See updated code above.  Hope the example works.  Come to think of it, maybe it will be easier if you just used a DataGridTemplateColumn instead.

Answer (score -1):

just try this..

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="CheckBoxStroke" Color="#8E8F8F"/>
    <Style x:Key="CheckRadioFocusVisual">
        <Setter Property="Control.Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Rectangle Stroke="Black" StrokeDashArray="1 2" StrokeThickness="1" Margin="14,0,0,0" SnapsToDevicePixels="true"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
        <Style x:Key="CheckBoxStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource CheckBoxFillNormal}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource CheckBoxStroke}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource EmptyCheckBoxFocusVisual}"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
                    <BulletDecorator SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Background="Transparent">
                        <BulletDecorator.Bullet>
                            <Microsoft_Windows_Themes:BulletChrome Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" IsChecked="{TemplateBinding IsChecked}" RenderMouseOver="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}" IsRound="True" RenderPressed="{TemplateBinding IsPressed}"/>
                        </BulletDecorator.Bullet>
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" RecognizesAccessKey="True"/>
                    </BulletDecorator>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="HasContent" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource CheckRadioFocusVisual}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="4,0,0,0"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>


        <CheckBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="186,31,0,0" Style="{DynamicResource CheckBoxStyle1}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Content="CheckBox"/>
    <CheckBox Margin="310,31,246.58,0" Style="{DynamicResource CheckBoxStyle1}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Content="CheckBox" d:LayoutOverrides="Width"/>
    <CheckBox HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,31,150.58,0" Style="{DynamicResource CheckBoxStyle1}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Content="CheckBox"/>
```