# Uncheck a radio button wpf

Tags: wpf, radio-button

I have a radio button that I want to represent both true and false value.

- When it false(uncheck), click it to make it true(check)
- When it true(check), click it to make it false(uncheck)

How can I do that with WPF?

Comment: Use a checkbox.  Radio buttons aren't meant to be used that way.

Comment: What a ridiculous comment. CheckBoxes are not substitutes for RadioButtons. CheckBoxes are all checked or unchecked independently. Radio buttons only allow a single selection within a group.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ToggleButton` which has `IsChecked` property represents both *true* and *false* values.

Comment: ToggleButton is ok. But it look bad in my design. How can I have a tooglebutton with radiobutton style

Comment: edit the template and put a radiobutton that bind to it's IsCheceked property

Comment: first may i suggest using a check box like so?:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975333/how-do-i-make-a-checkbox-look-like-a-radiobutton - Shimmy's answer